# Django + uWSGI + Nginx (13 Permission denied)

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

Пытаюсь запустить django. nginx выдает следующую ошибку:

```
2018/05/18 14:26:01 [crit] 32357#32357: *10 connect() to unix:/var/run/uwsgi.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/var/run/uwsgi.sock:", host: "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
```

Настройки nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name XX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
    charset utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /u0/git/django/templates/static;
        access_log off;
        etag            on;
        if_modified_since exact;
        gzip            on;
        gzip_min_length 1;
        gzip_types      *;
        gzip_comp_level 9;
        gzip_vary       on;
        expires         3d;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

Настройки uWSGI:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/u0/git/django
pidfile=/u0/tmp/uwsgi.pid
socket=/var/run/uwsgi.sock
chmod-socket=664
virtualenv=/home/norootuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5
home=/home/norootuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5
module=webservice.wsgi:application
master=true
processes=5
daemonize=/u0/tmp/uwsgi-daemonize.log
vacuum = true
```

Пробовал менять каталоги socket файла, его chmod - не помогает.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=nginx+Permission+denied

Comment: Сменив chmod на 666 - все заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сменив chmod на 666 - все заработало